# Перловый FCGI воркер перестаёт отвечать на запросы

Tags: perl

Код воркера:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use FCGI;
use POSIX qw(:signal_h);
use Time::HiRes qw(alarm);

my $socket = FCGI::OpenSocket(":9010", 10000);
my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $socket, FCGI::FAIL_ACCEPT_ON_INTR);

my $old_sigaction = POSIX::SigAction->new;
my $sigaction = POSIX::SigAction->new('sig_alarm', undef, POSIX::SA_RESTART);
POSIX::sigaction(SIGALRM, $sigaction, $old_sigaction) or die "can't sigaction: $!";

sub sig_alarm {

    print "alarm " . rand() . "\n";
    alarm(0.01);
} 
alarm(0.01);
while($request->Accept() >= 0) {

    print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n1\n";
}
```

Воркер получает запрос по fcgi протоколу и сразу в ответ возвращает строку "Content-type: text/plain\n\n1\n". Также, раз в 0.01 секунды, воркер обрабатывает сигнал SIGALRM. Обработчик выводит на консоль случайную строку.

Воркеру запросы передаёт nginx:

```
location /counter/ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9010;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Иногда воркер блокируется и перестаёт отвечать на запросы. Если натравить на него strace, то вывод будет таким:

```
futex(0x7f5035818e80, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
```

Легко добиться блокировки с помощью утилиты ab:

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/ab -k -c 80 -t 300 http://127.0.0.1/counter/
```

Как с этим справиться?

Comment: Думаю, что он не блокируется, а умирает. Посмотрите внимательно [документацию](https://metacpan.org/module/FLORA/FCGI-0.74/FCGI.PL) - там сказано, что *no die and warn handlers are installed by default* - то есть, если оно упадет, Вы об этом не узнаете.

А ещё - Accept возвращает 0 в случае успеха. А что он возвращает в других случаях не понятно. Хотя в примерах они также сравнивают с '>='. Странно.

Думаю, что у Вас  Accept возвращает отрицательное число (ошибка) и выходит с цикла обработки.

Comment: Нет, он не умирает. Я к нему scrace-ом коннекчусь после того, как он перестаёт обрабатывать запросы и там показано, на каком системном вызове он висит. И оказывается, что он заблокирован на вызове, подобном такому: futex(0x7f5035818e80, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL

Comment: потестил, если убрать print в sig_alarm - не блочится. тест с ab прошел раз 5-6.